# Can you still hold 2 non-light weapons even without the Dual Wielder feat?

Tags: dnd-5e, feats, two-weapon-fighting

I'm planning to dual-wield 2 versatile quarterstaffs (the Staff of Power and the Staff of Striking).

I plan to use the Staff of Striking as my main weapon, then use the Staff of Power as an off-hand weapon without using it to attack, just for the bonuses and possibly cast spells.

Is this allowed, even without taking the feat or fighting style?

Answer (score 23):

### You can't *attack* with both, but you can hold both.

It's not entirely clear to me, on second read, what you mean by "wield," so I'll just walk through the whole thing:

"Regular" two-weapon fighting requires two light melee weapons, each in one hand. (PHB p.195) The second attack uses the relevant ability modifier for to-hit rolls, but not for damage rolls.

With the fighting style you can now add the relevant ability modifier to your damage roll. Still no relaxing of the requirement that the weapons each be light. (PHB p.72, for example.)

The Dual Wielder feat modifies the requirement: "you can use two-weapon fighting [p. 195] even when the one-handed melee weapons you are wielding aren't light." (PHB p.165.)

There's nothing (shy of encumbrance) stopping you from *carrying* the two staves and taking the Attack action with one while holding the other. It's just that without meeting the (regular) TWF restrictions *you don't have the bonus action with which to make a second attack.* It's (regular) TWF that grants you the bonus action in the first place.

Answer (score 10):

### Yes.

You won't be able to attack with both weapons in the same round; in order for you to get a bonus attack without the class feature or feat, both weapons must be light.  That's demonstrated in the section on two weapon fighting:

> When you take the Attack action and attack with a light
>   melee weapon that you’re holding in one hand, you can
>   use a bonus action to attack with a different light melee
>   weapon that you’re holding in the other hand.

Since quarterstaves are versatile, however, they can be wielded with only one hand.  Just as you could attack with a quarterstaff while wearing a shield, you can attack with a quarterstaff while bearing another staff.

From the DMG:

> Unless a staff's description says otherwise, a staff can be used as a quarterstaff.

From the *Staff of Power* description:

> This staff can be wielded as a magic quarterstaff that grants a +2 bonus to attack and damage rolls made with it.

From the *Staff of Striking* description:

> This staff can be wielded as a magic quarterstaff that grants a +3 bonus to attack and damage rolls made with it.

Since you aren't intending to attack with more than one staff in a turn, and the staves in question can be treated as quarterstaves, you can indeed have one in each hand while you fight, using one for melee attacks and the other for its spells.

Answer (score 2):

Something that the other answers so far haven't stated explicitly yet is that the bonus from one staff doesn't apply to attacks made by the other. If you attack with the Staff of Striking, it will only add the +3 it itself grants to your attack and damage rolls. the +2 from the Staff of Power won't affect any of the damage rolls made by the Staff of Striking.

So while it is an option to wield them both as one-handed weapons, for pure damage from the Staff of Striking, it's probably a better idea to equip something else in your offhand that grants an attack and/or damage bonus to all attacks made, if something like that exists in 5e of course.

Comment: The staff of power also gives bonuses to AC, STs, and spell attack rolls.  It also allows the wielder to cast spells from it.

Answer (score -3):

just use one staff in two hands and make a attack with the other side as a light weapon using the staffs one handed damage with no modifier and the first attack as one handed damage with the modifier since your only holding one staff your added weight from the other side of the staff is 0 seems pretty light to me and since both hands are on the staff you have a weapon in each hand problem solved

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance. Can you support your claims by citing the relevant rules and/or evidence? Also: please use punctuation to make your answer easier to read.